# Queuing TCP/UDP calls on cloud made from React-Native app

Tags: react-native, tcp, udp, queuing

I am trying to implement a React-Native app through which a user can make phone calls to another user. How can I queue those calls? What server or tool to use?

I have heard of Twilio 'Queueing calls' but not sure if that does exactly what I am asking because I think it requires phone numbers for each use.